# np.loadtxt vs np.fromfile

Tags: python, numpy

All the problem are in the following example.

```
import numpy as np

x=np.arange(5).astype('float')
with open('test.txt', 'w') as flx :
    np.savetxt(flx,x)

with open('test.txt', 'r') as flx :
    x=np.loadtxt(flx)
print(x)

with open('test.txt', 'r') as flx :
    x=np.fromfile(flx)
print(x)
```

When I use `np.loadtxt`, everything is fine, but when I use `np.fromfile` method, the result is not the waited one (and it is very far from it).

```
[0. 1. 2. 3. 4.]
[1.39804329e-076 1.39804329e-076 1.39642638e-076 1.39804328e-076
 1.39804329e-076 1.21089429e-099 1.39737102e-076 1.39804329e-076
 1.39804329e-076 3.82834791e-086 1.39804329e-076 1.39804329e-076
 2.96620794e-260 1.39804329e-076 1.39804329e-076 1.39642638e-076]
```

First question : Why ?
Second question : How get the same result as `np.loadtxt` by using `np.fromfile` ?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: What version of numpy are you using? I can't get this to run: `TypeError: Mismatch between array dtype ('float64') and format specifier ('%.18e')` in 1.13.3

Comment: `np.__version__ ` gives me `1.14.5`

Comment: To load text `fromfile` requires a delimiter - read the whole docs.

Comment: I don't see you using `tofile` anywhere. I see you using `fromfile` on a file written with `savetxt`.

Comment: You are right, that a small mistake in my post, but I speek about `fromfile` and not `tofile`. I edit the post to correct that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks a lot hpaulj.

```
with open('test.txt', 'r') as flx :
    x=np.fromfile(flx)
print(x)
```

does not work, but

```
with open('test.txt', 'r') as flx :
    x=np.fromfile(flx, sep=' ')
print(x)
```

works ! Indeed, the default separator is void (`''`), so it is not adapt for load textfile.